# chamar include dentro js

Tags: javascript

achei um codigo que troca a url sem refresh, porem queria incluir duas páginas dentro do js conforme suas url, quando eu clico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="" data-tab-for="geral">Geral</a></li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="" data-tab-for="buna-silva">Bruna Silva</a></li>

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="" data-tab-for="amanda-castro">Amanda Castro</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
    <p id="geral">Geral</p>
    <p id="buna-silva" class="hide">Bruna Silva</p>
    <p id="amanda-castro" class="hide">Amanda Castro</p>
</div>
```

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

**js**

```
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-tab-for]");

var contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content>p");

tabs.forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener('click', tabClicked));

window.onpopstate = checkState;

history.replaceState({tabForId: tabs[0].dataset.tabFor}, null, ""+tabs[0].dataset.tabFor);

function showContent(id) {

  contents.forEach(content => {
    if (content.getAttribute('id') === id) 
        content.classList.remove('hide');
    else 
        content.classList.add('hide');
  });

  tabs.forEach(tab => {
    if (tab.dataset.tabFor === id) 
      tab.classList.add("active");
    else 
      tab.classList.remove("active");
   });

}

function tabClicked(e) {
  var contentId = e.target.dataset.tabFor;
  e.preventDefault();
  showContent(contentId);
  history.pushState({tabForId: contentId}, null, ""+contentId);

if(contentId == 'geral') {
  // linha do erro da variavel indefinida
  document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('lobby.php');?>";
} else {

  document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('private.php');?>";
}
console.log(content);
}

function checkState(e) {
  if(e.state) {
    console.log(e.state.tabForId);
    showContent(e.state.tabForId);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sam na verdade agora não puxa nada

Comment: foi burrice minha, ta chamando o require no console, só não ta incluindo na página http://prntscr.com/mu2x3w `if(contentId == 'geral') {
 
      document.querySelectorAll(".content")[0].innerHTML = "<?php require_once('lobby.php');?>";
      
      console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".content")[0].innerHTML = "<?php require_once('lobby.php');?>");
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll(".content")[0].innerHTML = "<?php require_once('private.php');?>";

      console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".content")[0].innerHTML = "<?php require_once('private.php');?>");
    }`

Comment: por enquanto ta vazio, mais vai ter html e php

Comment: Vc deveria usar Ajax pra isso, e não colocar uma página dentro do innerHTML.

Comment: @Sam oque tentei foi isso `function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost/public/' + contentId,
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            content.html(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}` deu esse erro http://prntscr.com/mu3bic

Answer (score 1):

Está dando erro na function `tabClicked`, fizendo que "content" não está definido, e não está mesmo, veja bem o corpo da function:

```
function tabClicked(e) {
    var contentId = e.target.dataset.tabFor;
    e.preventDefault();
    showContent(contentId);
    history.pushState({
        tabForId: contentId
    }, null, "" + contentId);

    if (contentId == 'geral') {
        // linha do erro da variavel indefinida
        document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('lobby.php');?>";
    } else {

        document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('private.php');?>";
    }
    console.log(content);  // <-este content, onde foi declarado???
}
```

Deixei a linha comentada para ajudar a identificar. Não sei o que queria observar aqui, talvez o `contentId`? Ou seria a variável `contents`?

Comment: realmente era falta de atenção

Answer (score -1):

```js
function showContent(id) {

  contents.forEach(content => {
    if (content.getAttribute('id') === id) 
        content.classList.remove('hide');
    else 
        content.classList.add('hide');
  });
```

tenta dar um console.log do content e ver o resultado.

Comment: ele ta pegando certo, nao sei pq da indefinida http://prntscr.com/mtzfeo

Comment: ```
if(contentId == 'geral') {
  // linha do erro da variavel indefinida
  document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('lobby.php');?>";
} else {

  document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('private.php');?>";
}
console.log(content);
}

```

talvez se vc remover esse console.log

Comment: console não tem nada a ver, o console só mostra se ta pegando a informação certa, é a "variavel" que não ta definida

Comment: mas o content não existe dentro da função tabClicked(e)

Comment: tenta salvar o resultado do querySelector numa var

Comment: vc ta certo, acho q vo precisa de ajax `if(contentId === 'geral') {
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".content"));
        document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('lobby.php');?>";
        alert(contentId);
    } else {
        document.querySelectorAll(".content").innerHTML = "<?php require_once('private.php');?>";
         alert(contentId);
    }` assim deu certo, mais sempre q uso ajax onde tem arquivo htaccess ele duplica a pagina, q complicaçaõ meu, nunca da certo

Comment: e se vc salvar o <body> do html direto numa variavel e utilizar ela como base.

Talvez tb se vc conseguir o Axios no seu projeto.

Comment: ele ta puxando só nao ta mostrando, só ajax msm salva http://prntscr.com/mtzoyq tem alguma ideia de como chama por ajax?

Comment: talvez isso possa te ajudar https://blog.especializati.com.br/como-fazer-requisicoes-ajax-com-o-axios/